# Javascript Navigator.geolocation

Tags: javascript, function, variables, geolocation, navigator

I am trying to return the position.coords.latitude and longitude as variables to use elsewhere in the code. How do I get the function to return usable variables?

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
     var lat = position.coords.latitude; 
     var lon = position.coords.longitude;
     var values = [lat, lon];

     return values;

  });
}   

console.log(values);
```

Comment: you don't; async functions don't return...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the callback methods.

Have a read of this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) { // success callback
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');

  var values = [crd.latitude, crd.longitude];
  doSomethingWithCoordinateValues(values);
};

function doSomethingWithCoordinateValues(coords) {
  // do something with 'coords'
}

function error(err) { // error callback
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

You could also have a read of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6847754/revisions) that states:

> If an inner function call is asynchronous, then all the functions 'wrapping' this call must also be asynchronous in order to 'return' a response.